# Crontab + Forever + node.js + NPM

Tags: ubuntu, putty, cron, node.js

I cant put my crontab to work. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04x64

So, this is what I did:

```
.root
.pw
.sudo apt-get update
.sudo apt-get install nodejs
.sudo apt-get install npm
.curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash
```

[I reload Putty]

```
.nvm install 0.12
.npm install steam
```

[Now I go to filezilla, upload the file.js into root directory]

```
.nvm use 0.12
.node file.js
```

[It executes the file.js sucessfuly, I reload Putty]

```
.nvm use 0.12
.npm install forever -g
.forever start file.js
```

[It will execute the file.js infinitely]

Now I want a restart to execute this commands. The thing is that "forever start" will not execute if I dont execute the "nvm use 0.12" in first place.

So:

```
.crontab -e
```

nano

```
.*/5 * * * * nvm use 0.12 && forever restart file.js
```

ctrl + x
saved

Result: It doesn't restarts.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you create a bash file and just execute that in the cron?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself.

```
0 * * * * root/.nvm/v0.12.4/bin/node /usr/local/bin/forever restart file.js
```

Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it is likely that your cron does not have a default environment and therefore you need to specify full path's for commands and files.

As @MiPnamic says, best to wrap your startup into a shell file and execute that instead. That also makes it easier to adjust should you need to - for example if you want to change from Node 0.12 to 0.10 or something else.

In addition, you can also set the default version in NVM by doing:

```
nvm alias default v0.12
```